# Immediate window behavior differences in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, immediate-window

I have noticed that the immediate window in VS 2010 behaves differently when debugging a C# project and a VB.NET project, although I haven't been able to find any specific documentation of this difference.

For C# projects, I can simply type in any expression, and it will be evaluated and displayed, i.e. typing in

> foo.bar == "baz"

will output

> false

In VB.NET, however, doing the same thing outputs nothing.

I have to put a question mark in front of the expression for it to work.

> ?foo.bar = "baz"
>
> false

Edit for clarity and my bad example above:

All other expressions exhibit the same behavior, including simple math such as '1 + 2'. Sometimes the error message is different though, as 1 + 2 results in the error 'Labels that are numbers must be followed by colons.'

Is there a way to 'fix' this behavior and make the VB.NET immediate window behave more like the C# one? Having to type a ? in front of every statement can be a pain when using it frequently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The semantics of the immediate windows are just different.  In C#, any expression or statement you enter is evaluated, and the result of the evaluation is printed to the window.  In VB.NET, you have to enter a complete statement; you can't enter a bare expression.  In your example, as you discovered, you need to use the 'Print' statement (the alias for which is `?`) if you want to print anything to the window.

One reason for this is that the semantics of the languages are different.  As Bob Kaufman mentioned, `=` can be an assignment operator or an equality test.  If the VB.NET window worked like the c# window, there would be no way to determine whether `a = b` meant "assign b to a" or "evaluate whether b is equal to a".

Assignments do not have a value in VB.NET; `a = b = 4` means "evaluate whether b is equal to 4, and assign the result of that evaluation to a."  This means that a will either be equal to true or false.

In C#, an assigment is also an expression with a value, so `a = b = 4` means "assign the value 4 to b, and assign the value of the expression (b = 4) to a."  This means that a will be equal to 4.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much makes sense. It's still a pain though, especially for simple property evaluation.

Comment: So basically, just put a `?` in front of your statements

Comment: @levininja absolutely; the question is more or less "why is that necessary?"

Answer (score 5):

The immediate window parser expects a *statement* if you don't use the ? command.  The command

```
foo.bar = "baz"
```

is legal in vb.net, it is an assignment statement, giving the *bar* field or property of the object foo the value "baz".  It is however going to complain if *bar* is a method of the class.  Similarly, "1+2" is not a valid statement in vb.net, the ? command helps the interpreter to understand that you meant to evaluate an expression.  To turn the = operator from an assignment into a comparison operator, you have to make the parser understand that an expression is being evaluated.  ? required.  Same thing for "1+2", the vb.net statement parser accepts a number at the start of a statement as a statement label, fit for a GoTo.

The C# language follows the curly brace languages standard where any expression is also a valid statement.  So "1+2" is interpreted as a valid statement without help from ?  Which is also the reason it needs a separate symbol for the equality operator (==), a parser wouldn't otherwise know the difference between an assignment statement and an expression.

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification!